# Check if the given figure is a lattice?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I have the following figure.

[image: Question]

The question is whether the given figure is a lattice or not. I think it is a lattice but the lecture notes say that it is not.
According to me every pair of points have a greatest lower bound and a least upper bound.

Comment: What's the least upper bound of $e$ and $h$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g$ and $f$ have two least upper bounds, namely $b$ and $c$. But in a lattice, the least upper bound is supposed to be unique. So no, it's not a lattice.

I'll tell you what raised my suspicions about this example, making me think that I agreed with your lecture notes. The first three layers from the bottom upwards look like the inclusion lattice of subsets of a 3 element set. But the higher layers do not look like that. In fact the 4th layer in that subset lattice would have to be just a single point, the maximum point of the whole lattice.